# What is the best way to display the main menu on my app?

Tags: android, mockup

I have created two wire frames for the main page of my app. I feel that these two options are not good for the main page. Does anyone have suggestions on how it can be improved?

[image: mockup1]

[image: mockup2]

Comment: Please review Android design guidelines. It seems like you've gone against quite a few things. Also, check spelling.

Comment: I really like the first approach. However, try to 1. Move your profile (the image) to navigation drawer header. 2. Try different colors for heading and subtext of the actions, as per material design guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Like most things, there is no magic bullet solution. Leveraging standards, for better or worse, can guide you down an established direction.

Your users are likely have seen and possibly gotten acquainted with the following: [Android Design Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/get-started/principles.html), [Google Multi-Screen Resources](http://www.google.com/think/multiscreen/whitepaper-sitedesign.html), [Apple HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/) and [W3C Mobile Web Application Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/mwabp/).

Let established patterns *influence* your design decisions but *make judgements* about what is appropriate for your business goal, user needs and technology constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding labels to the tabs and putting them at the bottom where they can be pressed with a single thumb tap.

[image]